# Download single record in CSV in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm using ruby csv library. When I'm trying to download multiple records it is working fine and downloading all the records in CSV file.

```
@assets = Asset.all
respond_to do |f|
  f.html
  f.csv { send_data @assets.to_csv }
  f.xls { send_data @assets.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
end
```

But when I'm trying to download single record. It is giving error

> undefined method `to_csv'

This is my code for a single record.

```
@assets = Asset.last
respond_to do |f|
  f.html
  f.csv {
    send_data @assets.to_csv
  }
end
```

This is my to_csv code

```
 def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |f|
      f << column_names
      all.each do |asset|
        f << asset.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you defined `self.to_csv` on the `app/models/asset.rb` ? If so can you post the code for this?

Comment: Yes I have defined it properly. That is why I'm able to download multiple records properly. Issue is coming when I'm trying to download one record.

Comment: Can you post the to_csv method from the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `to_csv` method should be called on `ActiveRecord` collection instead of a single record.

I beleive the error you are getting must be

> NoMethodError: undefined method `to_csv' for #< Asset:0x0000000xxxx>

Change

```
@assets = Asset.last
```

to

```
@assets = Asset.limit(1).order(id: :desc)
```

So you can tweak the code a bit to pass an collection to `to_csv` and it will work

```
@assets = Asset.limit(1).order(id: :desc)
respond_to do |f|
  f.html
  f.csv {
    send_data @assets.to_csv
  }
end
```

**EDIT:**

Well this is a workaround but it works

```
# If you only want the last record
@assets = Asset.limit(1).order(id: :desc)

# If you know the id or a specific condition
@assets = Asset.where(id: 1).limit(1)
```

Comment: Try this: `rails console` -> `User.all.to_csv`... or `User.first.to_csv`. You have to define it.

Comment: @whodini9 The issue is he's calling it on instance instead of collection

Comment: Instead of `User.first.to_csv` you have to call `User.first(1).to_csv`

Comment: `User.first(1).to_csv` will return you 1 record but in collection

Comment: I tried doing what you said but it is giving me empty CSV file. #<Asset:0x007ff832ee4b70> This is written inside it.

Comment: `User.first(1).to_csv` returns:
`NoMethodError: undefined method `to_csv' for #<Array:0x007fb241412850>. `to_csv` is not defined for arrays in Rails. If you have an array you can do `CSV.generate_line(array)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @DeepakMahakale It is perfectly working with where clause.